# How to change icon in the login page for Enterprise Portal

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Can anyone show me how to change the image on the login page. I went to the Default form under:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\FORMS

but I can't find the tag for the image. I am wondering where does it set the image on the login page?

[image]

And also, how do I change the background around the login form?

Comment: Related: [Same question](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/193561) in AX Community